# How does a jump between skills should be handled in Botium Box (testing Watson Assistant)?

Tags: bots, chatbot, botium-box

I am trying to understand how a jump between skills should be handled in Botium Box. I am testing the dialogues of my Watson Assistant skills and I am noticing something weird.

Differently from the jumps within one skill, where each row of my input test file (in my case excel file) contains the text of a different node, when I do a jump between skills, it seems like the text of the nodes is concatenated, and therefore to make the test case passing I should write all the text in one row of my excel file (very difficult to maintain)

If that is the case, how do I concatenate normal text and utterances variables? Is there a command for that? Or am I missing something in the configuration of my botium box?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know where the described behaviour is coming from, here are some comments:

Usually, **one** Watson Assistant is linked to **one** Dialog skill (and, for Plus plans, optionally a search skill). Botium can either connect to

- an assistant by using the Watson Assistant V2 SDK
- or a skill by using the Watson Assistant V1 SDK with the Skill legacy mode

If you plan to use multiple skills in your chatbot, then you have to develop some code to switch between the assistants - this is called an **Orchestrator** in IBM terms, and you can find example code by IBM [here](https://github.com/IBM/watson-assistant-multi-bot-agent).

In this case, the best option you have in Botium is to use the [Generic HTTP/JSON Connector](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24510469/Generic+HTTP+S+JSON+Connector) to connect to the API of the Orchestrator, instead of going directly to Watson APIs.

I wrote about a similar topic - how to choose a Botium connector - in [my blog](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-9-selecting-a-botium-connector-f27a56d55bf4).

Answer (score 0):

Florian, thanks for your reply. It is clear to me the concept of the orchestrator and I am actually using it as well as the HTTP/JSON Connector.
My question is more about how to write test cases in excel files that include both normal text and Utterances variables. For example, if I have in the utterances files:

[utterance file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNLiK.png)

Can I have in my test case something like:

[test case with text and utterance variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHb3e.png)

If that is the case, what is the key word needed to concatenate the text ("hello") and the utterance variable (GREETING)?

Comment: There is something similar available, maybe this helps - utterances support a "printf"-like syntax, see https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48922633/Composing+in+Text+files#printf